# installing a service app from .NET does not install it

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-services

I have read the other similar posts on this forum! However they haven't helped me
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Team System, on Windows 10. My Windows account has admin privileges,
Here is what I have done to achieve this:
Service app created and worker code independantly tested also the class on business..
i'm installing the service from cmd whit InstallUtil.exe.
this is the code of the service:

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    #region Abstracción clases 
    BLTerminal terminalService = new BLTerminal();
    Timer timer;
    protected FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    DAGeneral dAGeneral = new DAGeneral();
    #endregion
    #region Declaración de Variables
    string pathToFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathToFolder"];
    string targetPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["targetPath"];
    string extension = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["extensionFile"];
    string logPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logPath"];
    string TimeInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeInterval"];
    string TimeEnabled = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeEnabled"];
    #endregion

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    #region Método del Servicio
    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #endregion
    #region Metódo OnStart del servicio
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)

    {
        try
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            terminalService.LogService("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss"), logPath);
            timer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(TimeInterval);
            timer.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(TimeEnabled);
            terminalService.CreateBackup(pathToFolder, targetPath, extension, logPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dAGeneral.GuardarLogTerminalService(36, 1, $"error: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Metódo OnStop del servicio
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        terminalService.LogService("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss"), logPath);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Método de OnelapsedTime del servicio
    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        terminalService.LogService("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss"), logPath);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Where is the installer code?  With post-Vista Windows, just because your account belongs the Admin group, it doesn't mean that apps your run start with an Admin token.  You have to run the app "As Admin" (i.e., opt in to be an administrator).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is in a comment rather than in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the service itself for .NET Framework 4, but you are missing the installer. The installer is a class that you can define manually or with the help of the designer that is invoked when your assembly is registered via InstallUtil.exe

You can have a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer). The link refers .NET 4.